# Showing an operator is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, operator-algebras

I am trying to complete a problem where I have to show that the given operator is not linear:
$L[f] = \partial_t f + f\partial_x f$
I currently am using the superposition principle to formally show that it is in fact non linear, this is what I have currently
$L[f] = \partial_t f + f\partial_x f\\
L[\alpha u + \beta v] = [\alpha u + \beta v]\partial_t + [\alpha u + \beta v]\partial_x[\alpha u + \beta v]\\
=\partial_t\alpha u + \partial_t\beta v + [\alpha u + \beta v][\partial_x \alpha u + \partial_x \beta v]\\
= \partial_t\alpha u + \partial_t\beta v + \alpha u\partial_x \alpha u + \alpha u \partial_x \beta v + \beta v \partial_x \alpha u + \beta v \partial_x \beta v\\
= \alpha[\partial_t u + u\partial_x u] + \beta[\partial_t v + v\partial_x v] + \alpha u \partial_x \beta v + \beta v \partial_x \alpha u$

So this is non linear as we have the additional terms on the end.
Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct and works. It's perhaps quicker to just compare $L[f]$ and $L[-f]$ instead of showing the general case.

Comment: Actually, I noticed a small issue. The $\alpha u\partial_x \alpha u$ was treated as just $\alpha u\partial_x u$ (and similarly with $\beta$). You won't have an $\alpha L[u]+\beta L[v]$ in your answer.

Comment: You still have to show that the additional terms on the end are not always $0$. That is, you prove that there exist $u, v, \alpha, \beta$ that make the additional terms not $0$.

Comment: @yona to add to this comment, the problem is asking you to prove that something is *not* the case. In general, that means exhibit a counterexample. Your work looks like you tried to prove that $L$ is linear, ran into a problem, and concluded that it can't possibly be linear. That usually is the right way to start this kind of problem, but you should think of it as scratch work. All anyone wants to see is a simple example that demonstrates why $L$ is not linear. They don't so much care how you came up with it.